# GDX call a Class to display sprites movement

Tags: java, android, class, libgdx

I have

```
 public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements ImputProcessor
```

and have 3 static objects A B C and a Sprite A that travels between them

```
        @Override
  public void create () {
A B C
spriteA
}

@Override
public void render () {
A B C
spriteA

if(touched){

// all the calculus to move spriteA around when A,B or C is touched.
//............
batch.begin();
batch.draw(spriteA, 20, 20, 35, 35, 50, 50, mag_2M1,    mag_2M1, 90);
batch.end();
//...........
        }
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int     button) {
touched = true;
}
```

Because there will be a lot of sprites and the code is getting long I want to create a Class MovePlanes and move the code there for the movement to be called when touch event is actioned.
Is there a simple way?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Simple way to do what? Create a class?

Comment: May be creating a class is what I want (sorry new at this) My code just to move my sprites is almost 100 lines so far. I want to alleviate MyGdx of all this code to a different “page” and call it to draw when my true/false parameter are met when touch event is called.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a class for moving planes. Instead of that create a class named as Plane which extends sprite class and write method there to change position(x,y) and other things like width, height as you need.

And whenever you need to crate a plane create an object using the Plane class. In this way you can command the newly created plane object to move by calling changePosition() / movePlane() method which you have created in Plane class.

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: Makes sense but (unless I'm not seeing the all picture)my plane movement depends on multiple variable instances  like relation to other planes,are moving what part of the screen they sit, etc.  I control all these factors with true/ false statements and if I understood in you discrived case Ill still need to specify all these arguments in MyMain and only be calling Plane to move sprite accordantly. I want to on touch to call that Plane class verify witch plane to move and how
On touch event//have a class call start the movement and return to the main flow of the game.